# Subclassing models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, subclassing

I have two models, Article and Recipe, which have a bunch of the same attributes and methods.  I want to make the subclasses of a new class "Post" and move all their shared logic in there so I'm not maintaining duplicate code.  I've tried this:

```
class Recipe < Post; end
class Article < Post; end
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
     #all the shared logic
end
```

All of these classes are in the standard ./app/models folder.  This code, however, throws a ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid error when I go to /articles/new, for instance.  The error is:

> Could not find table 'posts'

Any idea how to set this up?

Comment: But have you creted the 'posts' table?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why don't you use modules?

```
module Features
  def hello
    p "hello"
  end
end

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Features
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Features
end


Recipe.new.hello
# => "hello"

Article.new.hello
# => "hello"
```

Comment: That's perfect.  I'm new to rails and didn't know about those.  Just read http://handyrailstips.com/tips/14-drying-up-your-ruby-code-with-modules and it makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Rails is using Single Table Inhritance pattern by default (just google for it), so when you're subclassing a model, all the resulting models will use the same database table (in this case `posts`). You can put all your common methods and validations in the `Post` model, and specific ones in the other classes, but all those classes will have access to each other's fields, because they share the same table (that's not a big problem though).

If you just want to share code (methods), you'd be better off just putting some common methods into a module in a file in the `lib` directory and including it in each model. Or you could put the module definition at the top if you're keeping all the models in a single file like in your example.