# Inheritance from ActiveRecord Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

Lets say there is a activerecord class called user, which is representative of user table of database.

But I have different type of users which have

- special functions
- special variables
- custom relations (Employer has_many companies, Employee belongs_to company :)

But also these users have a lot of functionality in common. So what I want to do is create classes for each different type of user then inherit them from user class.

- User < ActiveRecord::Base
- Employer < User
- Employee < User
- Customer < User

What is the best way of doing something like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of applications start out with a `User` model of some sort. Over time, as different kinds of users emerge, it might make sense to make a greater distinction between them. `Admin` and `Guest` classes are introduced, as subclasses of `User`. Now, the shared behavior can reside in `User`, and subtype behavior can be pushed down to subclasses. However, all user data can still reside in the users table.

All you need to do is add a `type` column to the `users` table that will hold the name of the class to be instantiated for a given row. Active Record takes care of instantiating the kind of object when it loads it from the database.

This technique is called **Single Table Inheritance** or STI (for short).

A very good recent article about STI is here: http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html

Comment: Perfect thank you. Lastly, what about custom relations for each class?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to this thread on models subclassing:

[Subclassing models in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852632/subclassing-models-in-rails)